# get all metrics which have alarms boto

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-cloudwatch

I am new to boto and trying to get all the metrics that have alarms. Can some one please guide me how to do that? Here is what I am trying to do. I can get all the metrics in the following way.

```
import boto.ec2.cloudwatch
conn = boto.ec2.cloudwatch.connect_to_region('ap-southeast-1')
metrics = conn.list_metrics()
for metric in metrics:
   print metric.name, metric.namespace
```

I know that there is a function "describe_alarms_for_metric" that returns the  alarms for a metric. However it is not working for me and gives me an empty list. Here is what I am trying.

```
for metric in metrics:
    print conn.describe_alarms_for_metric(metric.name, metric.namespace)
```

I can also see the list of all alarms using "describe_alarms" but I dont know which alarm is for what metric.

```
alarms = conn.describe_alarms()
for alarm in alarms:
    print alarm
```

Comment: `describe_alarms_for_metric` doesn't appear to be working, but you can get the metric from the alarm by doing `alarm.metric`

Answer (score 3):

`describe_alarms()` returns a list of [`boto.ec2.cloudwatch.alarm` objects](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/cloudwatch.html#module-boto.ec2.cloudwatch.alarm), which can be inspected to find out the metric and other details about the alarm.

```
alarms = conn.describe_alarms()
for alarm in alarms:
    print alarm.name
    print alarm.metric
    print alarm.namespace
```

Comment: Thanks @Ben . Its solved my problem But how can I get the list of all objects for alarms. I tried using dir() but I don't see these objects(name, metric, namespace).

Comment: The properties are all listed in the [docs](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/cloudwatch.html#module-boto.ec2.cloudwatch.alarm) I linked to in the answer. Is that what you're wondering?

Comment: I have looked up to the document and can see them but when i try dir(alarms), i dont get those properties. Thats what I was wondering about.

Answer (score 2):

For Boto3 apparently `describe_alarms_for_metric()` doesn't work unless you also supply a dimension - see the [documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cloudwatch.html#CloudWatch.Client.describe_alarms_for_metric):

> Dimensions (list) -- The dimensions associated with the metric. If the
>   metric has any associated dimensions, you must specify them in order
>   for the call to succeed.
>
> (dict) -- Expands the identity of a metric.
>
> Name (string) -- [REQUIRED] The name of the dimension.
>
> Value (string) -- [REQUIRED] The value representing the dimension
>   measurement.

With that requirement I'm not sure what the point of this API is. An alternative is to use `describe_alarms()` through the paginator then specify a filter.

You can use the example [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-samples/latest/catalog/python-cloudwatch-describe_alarms.py.html) as a base:

```
import boto3

# Create CloudWatch client
cloudwatch = boto3.client('cloudwatch')

# List alarms of insufficient data through the pagination interface
paginator = cloudwatch.get_paginator('describe_alarms')
for response in paginator.paginate(StateValue='INSUFFICIENT_DATA'):
    print(response['MetricAlarms'])
```

Then modify it to add a filter:

```
paginator = cloudwatch.get_paginator('describe_alarms')
page_iterator = paginator.paginate()
filtered_iterator = page_iterator.search("MetricAlarms[?MetricName==`CPUUtilization` && Namespace==`AWS/EC2`]")
for alarm in filtered_iterator:
    print(alarm)
```

More information in the API docs [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cloudwatch.html#CloudWatch.Client.describe_alarms) and [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/paginators.html#filtering-results-with-jmespath).